# Different notation $dP(x)$ and $P(dx)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Quick question that has been bugging me for a while: I have come across both the notation $dP(x)$ as well as $P(dx)$ when looking at the $\mathbb E[X]$ where $X$ is a continuous real random variable. Am I missing an important concept as to why both are used, rather than just one? Or are these notations simply equivalent?

Comment: Neither of them means anything in their own except that the integral is with respect to the measure $P.$ In fact, you can drop the "$dx$" symbols everywhere and simply write $\mathbf{E}(X) = \int\limits_\Omega X dP.$

Comment: They come handy when you have a function of two variables, say $x \in \Omega$ and $t \in \mathrm{T}$ and the measure $P$ is on $\Omega.$ But even then the fact that $P$ is defined on $\Omega$ should suffice...